# Keep getting count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have problem while storing data into database. It is saying `count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`

Here is my code.

```
$InsertRecords  = new App\Two263;
$InsertRecords->user_id = 1;
$InsertRecords->aca_year = "test";
$InsertRecords->school_id = '1';
$InsertRecords->school_name = '1';
$InsertRecords->prog_code = "1";
$InsertRecords->prog_name = "2";
$InsertRecords->no_stud_appeared = "3";
$InsertRecords->no_stud_passed = "14";
$InsertRecords->save();
```

Here is my database structure screenshot: http://prntscr.com/nwj0qj

Error screenshot: http://prntscr.com/nwj167

If I attempt to save record, this error comes up. I don't know what it has to do with the `count` function.

It's been 6 hours I'm trying to figure out this issue. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Is APP\Two263 an object you have created? Does it implement the Countable interface? If not I suspect that is where your problem lies

Comment: Please provide your model and the complete controller method code.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Two263` model add the fields in the `$fillable` array.

```
class Two263

...

protected $fillable = [ 'user_id', 'aca_year', 'school_id', 'school_name', 'prog_code', 'prog_name', 'no_stud_appeared', 'no_stud_passed'];
```

Comment: Why do I need to add this ? I'm not using Fillable feature.

Comment: it is used for mass assignment protection so you either use `guarded` as an empty array or you add this ofherwise you won't be able to persist your data.